# Usage Of "Pass"

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*pass*".  According to definition 3 of this [dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pass_1#pass_1__6) for "*pass*":

> def 3. to be successful in an examination or test by achieving a satisfactory standard

, which suggests that "*pass*" in this context should only be used with "*test*", "*exam*", or "*quiz*".  But then, I found [this](http://subjecta.ucsd.edu/whatIs.html):

> If you do not ***pass the Entry Level Writing Requirement***, you will need to demonstrate a minimum proficiency in composition through course work.

A "*requirement*" is certainly not a "*test*".  So, is the example sentence an error?  Would this rewrite:

> If you do not ***satisfy*** the Entry Level Writing Requirement,...

be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you shouldn’t stick to only that definition. The word **pass** means that you can go past or across many things including the **Entry Level Writing Requirement**.

Nevertheless your replacement with **satisfy** is fine too but you can also use some other versions such as:

> **to meet**
>
> **to comply with**

All of them convey a similar general idea.

Comment: But is "*pass a requirement*" wrong?

Comment: @meatie, no it's not wrong, it's fine.